# const char* member

Tags: c++, windows, tinyxml

I am storing a const char* returned from the following tinyxml2 function:

```
const char* tinyxml2::XMLElement::Attribute (const char * name, const char * value = 0)
```

http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_element.html#ae39be2f7677e470e0f76ccd73eea560c

However, I recently realized that the string data becomes corrupted over time, possibly after calling Attribute() a number of times. I'm going to change the const char* to a std::string but I just want to learn why this happened.

I tried looking through the source code but I don't understand why this would happen. It looks like Attribute() calls Value() which calls GetStr():

https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/blob/master/tinyxml2.cpp

Could anyone tell me why the data pointed to by the const char* returned by GetStr() would become corrupted?

Comment: Total speculation: It reads the entire file into a buffer and parses it in place, returning you a char* into the buffer. If whatever root tinyxml object owns the buffer is destroyed so is the buffer. What you see as corruption is probably just freed memory that hasn't been entirely written over yet.

Answer (score 1):

A look at the source reveals that it returns a pointer to your XML data.
Make sure you keep your XML data in-memory until you're done processing it, or copy the strings you need before deleting XML data.